# pdb shows stack frames with all local variables set to None

Tags: python, debugging, stack, pdb

I'm debugging some import error of a C library, either running the test suite using `py.test --pdb` or calling the erroneous import within ipython and dropping a pdb instance on errors. So far nothing unusual. What baffles me, there seem to be some stack frames with all local variables set to `None`:

```
(Pdb) dir()
['LLVMContextRef', 'LLVMExecutionEngineRef', 'LLVMFunctionsIterator', 'LLVMGlobalsIterator', 'LLVMMemoryBufferRef', 'LLVMModuleRef', 'LLVMObjectCacheRef', 'LLVMPassManagerBuilderRef', 'LLVMPassManagerRef', 'LLVMTargetDataRef', 'LLVMTargetLibraryInfoRef', 'LLVMTargetMachineRef', 'LLVMTargetRef', 'LLVMTypeRef', 'LLVMValueRef', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_decode_string', '_is_shutting_down', '_lib_dir', '_lib_name', '_make_opaque_ref', 'ctypes', 'get_library_name', 'os', 'x']
(Pdb) [locals()[x] for x in dir() if x != '__builtins__']
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'x']
(Pdb) down
> /usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py(365)__init__()
-> self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
(Pdb) dir()
['_FuncPtr', 'flags', 'handle', 'mode', 'name', 'self', 'use_errno', 'use_last_error']
(Pdb) name
'libllvmlite.so'
(Pdb)
```

As demonstrated, this doesn't affect all frames. In the corrupted frames, `__builtins__` seem to be the only thing remaining untouched. As the variable got passed through to the lower frame correctly and is visible there, I don't think it's a problem of the code itself and rather an issue of pdb. Any ideas what could cause this, or how to dive deeper into it?